# Zone AB 3-day pass in Montreal

Tags: trains, buses, fares, montreal

I live in Laval and need to go on campus for 3 consecutive days. I was curious to know how to purchase the 3-day pass so that I can begin using it early in the morning for the bus (Monday-Wednesday). It seems as though I may only use it when first purchasing it but that would mean I would have to pay for my bus fare and then get to use it for my metro / bus fares afterwards, since I can only purchase this at a metro station.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to purchase this at some pharmacies (did it just yesterday actually) and they give you the option of a cardboard card (best for visitors) or to buy an OPUS and load it with the 3 day pass, so you may recharge it later. You can buy it ahead of time, it starts on the day of your first use.

Answer (score 0):

STL Laval have a trip planner on their site. (Available in English.) Many depanneurs sell tickets, and may sell the passes as well.